# increase CoreMidi iOS USB transfer speed

Tags: ios, macos, usb, midi, coremidi

I'm writing an app which utilizes CoreMidi to exchange SysEx data with specific class-compliant USB-MIDI hardware.

I crosscompile the app for iOS and Mac, and on the Mac the MIDI data transfer rate is much higher than on iOS by default (can't be more specific for now, looks like more than twice as fast). This is both for sending data via MIDISend(3) and for reading data. Is there a way to ask the OS for the actual transfer rate, and to increase it on iOS?

The data I'm sending/receiving is in the order of MegaBytes, so this has a significant impact on the performance of my app.

Is there a USB transfer speed limitation in the OS or CoreMidi?

Comment: Keep in mind as well that if you use any real MIDI interfaces, your data transfer rate is very slow.  (31kbaud, not sure of the actual data rate, but it's slow)  While you are using USB interfaces now, someone might hook it up to a regular MIDI interface in the future.

Comment: thanks, not a problem here though, the app is tailored towards one specific device which does MIDI at USB speed. Reading up on USB now...